# Javascript: How to access the current index value inside an array stored function

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

If a function is stored in an array item, how can I gain access of the array's current index value inside the function?
For example, how can I set my function in order to get results similar to this?

```
arr['hello'](); // function returns 'hello'
arr['world'](); // function returns 'world'
arr[123]() // function returns 123
```

Comment: Would you please share what the Array `arr` contains? Per my understanding (of [MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)), Array index are integers. **Arrays cannot use strings as element indexes**. And hence the question.

Comment: @jsN00b If the `arr` is an object `{}`, you can use string indexing, maybe he is confused with the names, and actually just checked now, JS allows to have string indexes in array

Comment: @jsN00b you're right! **The term "array" is not correct**. Is an object that every item should contain the same function. In this function, I need to gain access to the current item identifier (what I called "index").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you know in advance which specific properties will be used, you'll need a Proxy.

```js
const prox = new Proxy(
  {},
  {
    get(_, prop) {
      return () => prop;
    }
  }
);

console.log(prox[123]());
console.log(prox.hello());    
console.log(prox['world']());
```

Since you have some non-numeric properties, you shouldn't use an array.